# sentence patterns/rules/formulas for imperative sentences …

Tags: nlp, nlg

Please let me ask if you know any ressources on imperative sentence patterns for natural language generation.

There’s probably some ressources online, but I did not really find any.

Imperative sentences, or command sentences, could be structured very simple, e.g.:

1) “Eat!” (intransitive action-verb + exclamation mark)

2) “Eat rice!” (transitive action-verb + noun (singular or plural in some cases) + exclamation mark)

3) “Eat healthy!” (intransitive action-verb + adverb)

… but the more words per sentence, the more complex it gets.

So maybe there’s some general patterns/formulas for creating different variations of such sentences in a grammatically correct sense.

EDIT, as it seems the question is unclear:

I want to generate imperative sentences, i.e. instructional sentences. Is there any pattern on how to create such sentences with NLG?

Comment: Do you have a dataset with few thousand imperative sentences ?

Comment: No, finding or building such a dataset would be part of the question.